# Highcharts: column overlaps when hiding by legend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have a problem with highcharts. I have a set of columns for a single category, and when i start hiding the columns using the legend names it starts to show a strange behaviour for example my default chart is as follows:
[image: default state]

After I start hiding columns it starts overlapping, the columns that should be visible act like the are, but the others stay there. Is there any known bug?
[image]

PS: I'm using highcharts-ng, all the series are added dynamically.

Comment: Try to set a [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange) paramter as 1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a known bug, but you can try to fix the space between two columns using something like:

```
plotOptions: {
            column: {
                borderWidth: 1,
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0,
                /* ... */
            },
/* ... */
}
```

Do you still have the overlapping with those options ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue after digging a bit on our code. We had somewhere in our css

```
rect{
   visibility: visible !important;
}
```

this was preventing non-visible columns to hide properly.